# A word for "conceptually clever"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm certain I know of a word that basically means "conceptually clever". A word that tells that something is creative and smart, but not necessarily good or well-executed. The words "clever" and "creative" infer it's something good, but the word I'm trying to find indicates that, while it might be a good idea in theory, it might not be so in practice.

For further clarification: this word should preferably not imply that something is either good or bad. For instance, it should be possible to use the same word when referring to both good and bad ideas that are still clever.

Any idea on what it could be? Thanks in advance!

Example sentence:
"I think this game concept is [word], but perhaps you should try something different."

Comment: Are you thinking of *innovative*?

Comment: Has _radical_ undergone too much amelioration now?

Comment: @terdon "innovative" doesn't imply "impractical".

Comment: "well-intentioned" feels like it's in the right direction but not quite right.

Comment: I've edited my question for further clarification

Comment: If there was such a critter, you'd be able to track him down by using one thesaurus after another, starting from synonyms for either "conceptual" or "clever". What happens when you try that, please? Either way, what difference d'you see between "conceptually" and any other kind of clever?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I did search there, but none of the words seemed fitting. The difference is subtle, but it's basically that clever already implies it's a good idea, whereas what I'm looking for doesn't imply anything, just that it took intelligence/creativity to conceive that idea - its applicability or effectiveness being unknown/irrelevant. For the time being, I'm using a word I made up from "concipere" (concept) and "kleave" (clever): "kleaper".

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for *chimerical*, which has both connotations (but somewhat negative overall):

> **chimerical**
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1. unreal; imaginary; visionary
> 2. wildly fanciful; highly unrealistic
>
> *A few weeks ago the notion of a classic but modernized and fully realized Metroid game would have seemed chimerical.*

You might also consider *visionary*, which historically (see [synonym discussion on the Merriam-Webster definition for chimercal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chimerical)) has a similar meaning and may be more recognisable, but is more likely to be mistaken for outright praise.